Sending a notification targeting users by language or country/region doesn't work using Firebase Console
While composing a notification in Firebase Console you can target user segments by various criteria. I need to cover multiple languages, so I expected I could send one notification per language and use the language or country/region parameters for targeting the respective user segments.
That didn't work. Neither on Android nor on iOS. My own devices didn't receive anything and in the statistics I can see that no notification was send.
When sending notifications using the Firebase Console without the target options language or country/region it works fine.
For context, I use the following Firebase services in my project:

Authentication
Firestore
Storage
Functions
Messaging

So I'm not using Firebase Analytics – could this be an issue?
Does anyone know about the problem or even has a solution?
